# Can I find the frequency when I have a signal is an array on python?

Tags: signal-analysis, fourier-transform

I got an signal:

```
signal = [
+0.0000000000, +0.5924659585, -0.0947343455, +0.1913417162, +1.0000000000, +0.4174197128, +0.3535533906,
+1.2552931065,
+0.8660254038, +0.4619397663, +1.3194792169, +1.1827865776, +0.5000000000, +1.1827865776, +1.3194792169,
+0.4619397663,
+0.8660254038, +1.2552931065, +0.3535533906, +0.4174197128, +1.0000000000, +0.1913417162, -0.0947343455,
+0.5924659585,
-0.0000000000, -0.5924659585, +0.0947343455, -0.1913417162, -1.0000000000, -0.4174197128, -0.3535533906,
-1.2552931065,
-0.8660254038, -0.4619397663, -1.3194792169, -1.1827865776, -0.5000000000, -1.1827865776, -1.3194792169,
-0.4619397663,
-0.8660254038, -1.2552931065, -0.3535533906, -0.4174197128, -1.0000000000, -0.1913417162, +0.0947343455,
-0.5924659585,
+0.0000000000, +0.5924659585, -0.0947343455, +0.1913417162, +1.0000000000, +0.4174197128, +0.3535533906,
+1.2552931065,
+0.8660254038, +0.4619397663, +1.3194792169, +1.1827865776, +0.5000000000, +1.1827865776, +1.3194792169,
+0.4619397663,
+0.8660254038, +1.2552931065, +0.3535533906, +0.4174197128, +1.0000000000, +0.1913417162, -0.0947343455,
+0.5924659585,
+0.0000000000, -0.5924659585, +0.0947343455, -0.1913417162, -1.0000000000, -0.4174197128, -0.3535533906,
-1.2552931065,
-0.8660254038, -0.4619397663, -1.3194792169, -1.1827865776, -0.5000000000, -1.1827865776, -1.3194792169,
-0.4619397663,
-0.8660254038, -1.2552931065, -0.3535533906, -0.4174197128, -1.0000000000, -0.1913417162, +0.0947343455,
-0.5924659585,
+0.0000000000, +0.5924659585, -0.0947343455, +0.1913417162, +1.0000000000, +0.4174197128, +0.3535533906,
+1.2552931065,
+0.8660254038, +0.4619397663, +1.3194792169, +1.1827865776, +0.5000000000, +1.1827865776, +1.3194792169,
+0.4619397663,
+0.8660254038, +1.2552931065, +0.3535533906, +0.4174197128, +1.0000000000, +0.1913417162, -0.0947343455,
+0.5924659585,
+0.0000000000, -0.5924659585, +0.0947343455, -0.1913417162, -1.0000000000, -0.4174197128, -0.3535533906,
-1.2552931065,
-0.8660254038, -0.4619397663, -1.3194792169, -1.1827865776, -0.5000000000, -1.1827865776, -1.3194792169,
-0.4619397663,
-0.8660254038, -1.2552931065, -0.3535533906, -0.4174197128, -1.0000000000, -0.1913417162, +0.0947343455,
-0.5924659585,
-0.0000000000, +0.5924659585, -0.0947343455, +0.1913417162, +1.0000000000, +0.4174197128, +0.3535533906,
+1.2552931065,
+0.8660254038, +0.4619397663, +1.3194792169, +1.1827865776, +0.5000000000, +1.1827865776, +1.3194792169,
+0.4619397663,
+0.8660254038, +1.2552931065, +0.3535533906, +0.4174197128, +1.0000000000, +0.1913417162, -0.0947343455,
+0.5924659585,
-0.0000000000, -0.5924659585, +0.0947343455, -0.1913417162, -1.0000000000, -0.4174197128, -0.3535533906,
-1.2552931065,
-0.8660254038, -0.4619397663, -1.3194792169, -1.1827865776, -0.5000000000, -1.1827865776, -1.3194792169,
-0.4619397663,
-0.8660254038, -1.2552931065, -0.3535533906, -0.4174197128, -1.0000000000, -0.1913417162, +0.0947343455,
-0.5924659585,
+0.0000000000, +0.5924659585, -0.0947343455, +0.1913417162, +1.0000000000, +0.4174197128, +0.3535533906,
+1.2552931065,
+0.8660254038, +0.4619397663, +1.3194792169, +1.1827865776, +0.5000000000, +1.1827865776, +1.3194792169,
+0.4619397663,
+0.8660254038, +1.2552931065, +0.3535533906, +0.4174197128, +1.0000000000, +0.1913417162, -0.0947343455,
+0.5924659585,
+0.0000000000, -0.5924659585, +0.0947343455, -0.1913417162, -1.0000000000, -0.4174197128, -0.3535533906,
-1.2552931065,
-0.8660254038, -0.4619397663, -1.3194792169, -1.1827865776, -0.5000000000, -1.1827865776, -1.3194792169,
-0.4619397663,
-0.8660254038, -1.2552931065, -0.3535533906, -0.4174197128, -1.0000000000, -0.1913417162, +0.0947343455,
-0.5924659585,
-0.0000000000, +0.5924659585, -0.0947343455, +0.1913417162, +1.0000000000, +0.4174197128, +0.3535533906,
+1.2552931065,
+0.8660254038, +0.4619397663, +1.3194792169, +1.1827865776, +0.5000000000, +1.1827865776, +1.3194792169,
+0.4619397663,
+0.8660254038, +1.2552931065, +0.3535533906, +0.4174197128, +1.0000000000, +0.1913417162, -0.0947343455,
+0.5924659585,
+0.0000000000, -0.5924659585, +0.0947343455, -0.1913417162, -1.0000000000, -0.4174197128, -0.3535533906,
-1.2552931065,
-0.8660254038, -0.4619397663, -1.3194792169, -1.1827865776, -0.5000000000, -1.1827865776, -1.3194792169,
-0.4619397663,
-0.8660254038, -1.2552931065, -0.3535533906, -0.4174197128, -1.0000000000, -0.1913417162, +0.0947343455,
-0.5924659585,
-0.0000000000, +0.5924659585, -0.0947343455, +0.1913417162, +1.0000000000, +0.4174197128, +0.3535533906,
+1.2552931065,
+0.8660254038, +0.4619397663, +1.3194792169, +1.1827865776, +0.5000000000, +1.1827865776, +1.3194792169,
+0.4619397663,
+0.8660254038, +1.2552931065, +0.3535533906, +0.4174197128, +1.0000000000, +0.1913417162, -0.0947343455,
+0.5924659585,
+0.0000000000, -0.5924659585, +0.0947343455, -0.1913417162, -1.0000000000, -0.4174197128, -0.3535533906,
-1.2552931065,]
```

How can I convert into frequency, when there is no x value or y value.

Comment: Well, what does your `signal` vector represent? Probably samples of a signal with a constant sampling rate? In that case, you want to revisit what [tag:fourier-transform] is and how to apply it to a discrete-time signal. Please, also don't abuse the [tag:dsp-core] tag (read its description). Also, removing the [tag:python] tag, as this isn't specific to python.

Comment: Oh, this is just the **third** replica of https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/74539/what-is-the-formula-to-calculate-the-frequency-response . Please don't repost your same question multiple times.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the formula to calculate the frequency response?](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/74539/what-is-the-formula-to-calculate-the-frequency-response)